Solaris 10 make Error code 1 Fatal Error when trying to build python 2.7.16
I am trying to get Python 2.7.16 working on my Solaris 10 installation I have Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 I downloaded the XZ compressed source tarball from python downloads Then I extracted it and followed the instructions in the readme and on the Python website build instructions Here is what I did and what was outputted I saved them using script
# /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/configure --with-[py   pydebug
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking for python2.7... no
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... sunos5
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... no
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for c++... no
configure: WARNING:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "c++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for --with-suffix... 
checking for case-insensitive build directory... no
checking LIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION).a
checking LINKCC... $(PURIFY) $(MAINCC)
checking for GNU ld... no
checking for --enable-shared... no
checking for --enable-profiling... no
checking LDLIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION).a
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ar... no
checking for aal... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/install-sh -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/install-sh -c -d
checking for --with-pydebug... yes
checking whether cc accepts -OPT:Olimit=0... yes
checking for --enable-optimizations... no
checking for --with-lto... no
checking target system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking for -llvm-profdata... no
checking for llvm-profdata... ''
checking whether pthreads are available without options... yes
checking whether c++ also accepts flags for thread support... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking asm/types.h usability... no
checking asm/types.h presence... no
checking for asm/types.h... no
checking crypt.h usability... yes
checking crypt.h presence... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking conio.h usability... no
checking conio.h presence... no
checking for conio.h... no
checking direct.h usability... no
checking direct.h presence... no
checking for direct.h... no
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking grp.h usability... yes
checking grp.h presence... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking ieeefp.h usability... yes
checking ieeefp.h presence... yes
checking for ieeefp.h... yes
checking io.h usability... no
checking io.h presence... no
checking for io.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking process.h usability... no
checking process.h presence... no
checking for process.h... no
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking shadow.h usability... yes
checking shadow.h presence... yes
checking for shadow.h... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking thread.h usability... yes
checking thread.h presence... yes
checking for thread.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking sys/audioio.h usability... yes
checking sys/audioio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/audioio.h... yes
checking sys/bsdtty.h usability... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h presence... no
checking for sys/bsdtty.h... no
checking sys/epoll.h usability... no
checking sys/epoll.h presence... no
checking for sys/epoll.h... no
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/loadavg.h usability... yes
checking sys/loadavg.h presence... yes
checking for sys/loadavg.h... yes
checking sys/lock.h usability... yes
checking sys/lock.h presence... yes
checking for sys/lock.h... yes
checking sys/mkdev.h usability... yes
checking sys/mkdev.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mkdev.h... yes
checking sys/modem.h usability... no
checking sys/modem.h presence... no
checking for sys/modem.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking sys/random.h usability... yes
checking sys/random.h presence... yes
checking for sys/random.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/termio.h usability... yes
checking sys/termio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/termio.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking sys/wait.h usability... yes
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking pty.h usability... no
checking pty.h presence... no
checking for pty.h... no
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking netpacket/packet.h usability... no
checking netpacket/packet.h presence... no
checking for netpacket/packet.h... no
checking sysexits.h usability... yes
checking sysexits.h presence... yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth.h... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth/bluetooth.h... no
checking linux/tipc.h usability... no
checking linux/tipc.h presence... no
checking for linux/tipc.h... no
checking spawn.h usability... yes
checking spawn.h presence... yes
checking for spawn.h... yes
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking alloca.h usability... yes
checking alloca.h presence... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking whether sys/types.h defines makedev... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... (cached) yes
checking for linux/netlink.h... no
checking for clock_t in time.h... yes
checking for makedev... yes
checking Solaris LFS bug... no
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 4
checking size of void *... 4
checking size of short... 2
checking size of float... 4
checking size of double... 8
checking size of fpos_t... 8
checking size of size_t... 4
checking size of pid_t... 4
checking for long long support... yes
checking size of long long... 8
checking for long double support... yes
checking size of long double... 12
checking for _Bool support... yes
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking size of uintptr_t... 4
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... yes
checking size of time_t... 4
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 4
checking for --enable-toolbox-glue... no
checking for --enable-framework... no
checking for dyld... no
checking SO... .so
checking LDSHARED... $(CC) -G
checking CCSHARED... -Kpic
checking LINKFORSHARED... 
checking CFLAGSFORSHARED... 
checking SHLIBS... $(LIBS)
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for library containing sem_init... -lrt
checking for textdomain in -lintl... yes
checking for t_open in -lnsl... yes
checking for socket in -lsocket... yes
checking for --with-libs... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for --with-system-expat... no
checking for --with-system-ffi... no
checking for --with-tcltk-includes... default
checking for --with-tcltk-libs... default
checking for --with-dbmliborder... 
checking for --with-signal-module... yes
checking for --with-dec-threads... no
checking for --with-threads... yes
checking if PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM is supported... yes
checking for pthread_sigmask... yes
checking for pthread_atfork... yes
checking if --enable-ipv6 is specified... yes
checking if RFC2553 API is available... yes
checking ipv6 stack type... solaris
checking for OSX 10.5 SDK or later... no
checking for --with-doc-strings... yes
checking for --with-tsc... no
checking for --with-pymalloc... yes
checking for --with-valgrind... no
checking for --with-wctype-functions... no
checking for dlopen... yes
checking DYNLOADFILE... dynload_shlib.o
checking MACHDEP_OBJS... MACHDEP_OBJS
checking for alarm... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for getitimer... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for chown... yes
checking for clock... yes
checking for confstr... yes
checking for ctermid... yes
checking for execv... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for fchown... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for fpathconf... yes
checking for ftime... yes
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for getgroups... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for getpeername... yes
checking for getpgid... yes
checking for getpid... yes
checking for getentropy... no
checking for getpriority... yes
checking for getresuid... no
checking for getresgid... no
checking for getpwent... yes
checking for getspnam... yes
checking for getspent... yes
checking for getsid... yes
checking for getwd... yes
checking for initgroups... yes
checking for kill... yes
checking for killpg... yes
checking for lchown... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for mkfifo... yes
checking for mknod... yes
checking for mktime... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for mremap... no
checking for nice... yes
checking for pathconf... yes
checking for pause... yes
checking for plock... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for pthread_init... no
checking for putenv... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for sem_open... yes
checking for sem_timedwait... yes
checking for sem_getvalue... yes
checking for sem_unlink... yes
checking for setegid... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setgid... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for setregid... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setsid... yes
checking for setpgid... yes
checking for setpgrp... yes
checking for setuid... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for setlocale... (cached) yes
checking for setregid... (cached) yes
checking for setreuid... (cached) yes
checking for setresuid... no
checking for setresgid... no
checking for setsid... (cached) yes
checking for setpgid... (cached) yes
checking for setpgrp... (cached) yes
checking for setuid... (cached) yes
checking for setvbuf... (cached) yes
checking for snprintf... (cached) yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for siginterrupt... yes
checking for sigrelse... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for tcsetpgrp... yes
checking for tempnam... yes
checking for timegm... no
checking for times... yes
checking for tmpfile... yes
checking for tmpnam... yes
checking for tmpnam_r... yes
checking for truncate... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for utimes... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for wait3... yes
checking for wait4... yes
checking for wcscoll... yes
checking for _getpty... no
checking for lchmod... no
checking for chroot... yes
checking for link... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for fchdir... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for epoll... no
checking for kqueue... no
checking for ctermid_r... no
checking for flock declaration... no
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for broken unsetenv... no
checking for true... true
checking for inet_aton in -lc... yes
checking for chflags... no
checking for lchflags... no
checking for inflateCopy in -lz... yes
checking for hstrerror... no
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for setgroups... yes
checking for openpty... no
checking for openpty in -lutil... no
checking for openpty in -lbsd... no
checking for forkpty... no
checking for forkpty in -lutil... no
checking for forkpty in -lbsd... no
checking for memmove... yes
checking for fseek64... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking for fstatvfs... yes
checking for ftell64... no
checking for ftello... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for getpgrp... yes
checking for setpgrp... (cached) yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for major... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking getaddrinfo bug... no
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... no
checking whether tzname is declared... yes
checking for tzname... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_flags... no
checking for struct stat.st_gen... no
checking for struct stat.st_birthtime... no
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for time.h that defines altzone... yes
checking whether sys/select.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for addrinfo... yes
checking for sockaddr_storage... yes
checking whether char is unsigned... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for working signed char... yes
checking for prototypes... yes
checking for variable length prototypes and stdarg.h... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking if sockaddr has sa_len member... no
checking whether va_list is an array... no
checking for gethostbyname_r... yes
checking gethostbyname_r with 6 args... no
checking gethostbyname_r with 5 args... yes
checking for __fpu_control... no
checking for __fpu_control in -lieee... no
checking for --with-fpectl... no
checking for --with-libm=STRING... default LIBM="-lm"
checking for --with-libc=STRING... default LIBC=""
checking whether C doubles are little-endian IEEE 754 binary64... yes
checking whether C doubles are big-endian IEEE 754 binary64... no
checking whether C doubles are ARM mixed-endian IEEE 754 binary64... no
checking whether we can use gcc inline assembler to get and set x87 control word... yes
checking for x87-style double rounding... no
checking whether tanh preserves the sign of zero... yes
checking for acosh... yes
checking for asinh... yes
checking for atanh... yes
checking for copysign... yes
checking for erf... yes
checking for erfc... yes
checking for expm1... yes
checking for finite... yes
checking for gamma... yes
checking for hypot... yes
checking for lgamma... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking for round... yes
checking for tgamma... yes
checking whether isinf is declared... yes
checking whether isnan is declared... yes
checking whether isfinite is declared... yes
checking whether POSIX semaphores are enabled... yes
checking for broken sem_getvalue... no
checking digit size for Python's longs... no value specified
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking size of wchar_t... 4
checking for UCS-4 tcl... no
checking whether wchar_t is signed... yes
checking what type to use for unicode... unsigned short
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether right shift extends the sign bit... yes
checking for getc_unlocked() and friends... yes
checking how to link readline libs... none
checking for rl_callback_handler_install in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_pre_input_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_display_matches_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_resize_terminal in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_matches in -lreadline... no
checking for broken nice()... no
checking for broken poll()... no
checking for working tzset()... yes
checking for tv_nsec in struct stat... yes
checking for tv_nsec2 in struct stat... no
checking curses.h usability... yes
checking curses.h presence... yes
checking for curses.h... yes
checking ncurses.h usability... no
checking ncurses.h presence... no
checking for ncurses.h... no
checking for term.h... yes
checking whether mvwdelch is an expression... yes
checking whether WINDOW has _flags... yes
checking for is_pad... no
checking for is_term_resized... no
checking for resize_term... no
checking for resizeterm... no
checking for immedok... yes
checking for syncok... yes
checking for wchgat... no
checking for filter... yes
checking for has_key... no
checking for typeahead... yes
checking for use_env... yes
configure: checking for device files
checking for /dev/ptmx... yes
checking for /dev/ptc... no
checking for %lld and %llu printf() format support... yes
checking for %zd printf() format support... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for build directories... checking for --with-computed-gotos... no value specified
checking whether cc supports computed gotos... yes
done
checking for ensurepip... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile.pre
config.status: creating Modules/Setup.config
config.status: creating Misc/python.pc
config.status: creating Modules/ld_so_aix
config.status: creating pyconfig.h
config.status: pyconfig.h is unchanged
creating Modules/Setup
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile
# /usr/lib/ccs/        ccs/bin/make
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/_warnings.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/_warnings.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/Python-ast.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/Python-ast.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/asdl.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/asdl.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/ast.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ast.c
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ast.c", line 1974: warning: statement not reached
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ast.c", line 2426: warning: statement not reached
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ast.c", line 2533: warning: statement not reached
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/bltinmodule.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/bltinmodule.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/ceval.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c", line 2153: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c", line 3873: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c", line 3909: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c", line 4865: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/ceval.c", line 4888: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/compile.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/compile.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/codecs.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/codecs.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/errors.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/errors.c
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/errors.c", line 108: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/errors.c", line 108: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/errors.c", line 172: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/errors.c", line 673: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/frozen.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/frozen.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/frozenmain.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/frozenmain.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/future.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/future.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getargs.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getargs.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getcompiler.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getcompiler.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getcopyright.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getcopyright.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DPLATFORM='"sunos5"' -o Python/getplatform.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getplatform.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getversion.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getversion.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/graminit.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/graminit.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/import.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/import.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -I. -o Python/importdl.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/importdl.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/marshal.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/marshal.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/modsupport.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/modsupport.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/mystrtoul.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/mystrtoul.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/mysnprintf.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/mysnprintf.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/peephole.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/peephole.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pyarena.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pyarena.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pyctype.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pyctype.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pyfpe.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pyfpe.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pymath.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pymath.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pystate.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pystate.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pythonrun.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pythonrun.c
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pythonrun.c", line 1276: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/random.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/random.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/structmember.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/structmember.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/symtable.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/symtable.c
"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/symtable.c", line 437: warning: statement not reached
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/sysmodule.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/sysmodule.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/traceback.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/traceback.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getopt.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/getopt.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pystrcmp.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pystrcmp.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/pystrtod.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/pystrtod.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/dtoa.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/dtoa.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/formatter_unicode.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/formatter_unicode.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/formatter_string.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/formatter_string.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/dynload_shlib.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/dynload_shlib.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/thread.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Python/thread.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/config.o Modules/config.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DPYTHONPATH='":plat-sunos5:lib-tk:lib-old"' \
    -DPREFIX='"/usr/local"' \
    -DEXEC_PREFIX='"/usr/local"' \
    -DVERSION='"2.7"' \
    -DVPATH='"/Desktop/Python-2.7.16"' \
    -o Modules/getpath.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Modules/getpath.c
cc -c  -g -O  -I. -IInclude -I/Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Include  -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
      -DGITVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -DGITTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -DGITBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o /Desktop/Python-2.7.16/Modules/getbuildinfo.c
rm -f libpython2.7.a
ar rc libpython2.7.a Modules/getbuildinfo.o
sh: ar: not found
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libpython2.7.a'


sh: ar: not found is the important part of the error. (Does Solaris really not come with ar?)

From what I can tell, @Shawn, Solaris indeed doesn't have ar.  The instructions I find for building static libraries on Solaris seem to use the C and / or C++ compiler (with appropriate options) to build them.  And I note that Autoconf has a built in test macro for the presence of an ar command, which suggests that that command has not traditionally been considered safe to assume present.  The configure output in the question appears to show that test having been performed (with negative result), but apparently nothing is done about it.

The error means that you do not have ar installed.
Verify it first:
which ar

If not installed try:
pkg install gnu-binutils

if not then
pkg search binutils

If not try
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -i binutils
export PATH=/opt/csw/bin:$PATH

If nothing works contact your system administrator or build from the source:
Download or clone GNU Binutils sources
./configure
make
make install


I was able to install binutils but I can't add it to the path, I tried the export PATH=/opt/csw/bin:$PATH but it just told me that PATH=/opt/csw/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/openwin/bin: is not an identifier
I am using root as my account if that changes anything. I've tried adding things to my path before, but its never worked.

I eventually figured out how to get what I needed in my path, I just put the PATH= command with all the path things I wanted in my .dtprofile file as well as an export PATH at the end for good measure. I've re-run it with ar now in my path and this is the output google drive link, though I am concerned about the necessary bits to build these modules that are missing, because of that I haven't tried running the install.sh sript with the supplied parameters.

Python does seem to work now, i don't know if the missing things needed for some modules are integral to the use of python, but it prints hello world.
